# @OneToMany duplicates entries

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tblrelease")
public class Release implements Serializable  {    

    ... 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "release")
    public Set<ReleaseIssue> getIssues() {
        return issues;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tblissue")
public class ReleaseIssue implements Serializable {

   ...

   @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "relId", nullable = false)
    public Release getRelease() {
        return release;
    }
}
```

If I use this setting I get following exception: *org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ...*
Main cause is that the jsp wants to access the issues of a release an fails because it wants to access the proxy outside a session.

If I use FetchType = EAGER I have duplicates in releases. The Set contains so many duplicates of one release object as the release object has Issues.

Comment: Not an answer, but the fact that your Set, a collection class designed to not allow duplicates, has duplicates indicates a problem within a problem - you do not have proper hashCode() and equals() methods on your entities. Letting your IDE generate those will make the problem of duplicates go away, but you generally do not want to EAGER load a oneToMany. If you paste `LazyInitializationException` into the search box on the top right however, you get a mountain of duplicate questions.

Comment: Hi Gimby, thanks for the help. It workes fine. If you paste yout text into an answer I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

In you DAO classes, you can simply use

```
for(ReleaseIssue issue : release.getIssues(){
    Hibernate.initialize(issue)
}
```

This will initialize the set release objects, when you are retrieving them in jsp.